# Radius of Convergence for Complex Series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

So I have this complex sequence:

$$f(z)\frac{z-19}{z^2-8z-9}=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)^{k+1}+2\left(-1\right)^k\right)z^k$$

I am trying to show that the radius of convergence is $1$ using a convergence test to find $L$. Anyone have any idea? I trying using the ratio test $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}=\dfrac{z_{n+1}}{z_n}$ But cannot seem to show this. If anyone has any idea how to simply do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We need $$\dfrac19\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac z9\right)^k+2\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-z)^k$$

Now use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence)